# Is there any way to extract the Auto Tag from Android images

Tags: android, flutter

On my Samsung Galaxy in my Gallery my Images have tags (Pet, Dogs, Labradors), is there a way to access this information programmatically for Images taken or Images in Gallery ?

[image]

Comment: This is a built-in Samsung feature. You cannot access it since Samsung do not provide api to access to this feature

Comment: shame its a great feature Thanks.